# Obligar la seleción de un checkbox de un grupo en Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo un conjunto de casillas de verificación `CheckBox` y me gustaria añadir que sea obligatorio tener uno seleccionado, es decir que actue como si fuese un `RadioButton` pero permitiendo multiple-selección.

Los elementos `CheckBox` están dentro de un linearLayout

Comment: Si tienes muchos elementos puedes crear una RecyclerView y controlar el check al clickar el item. Puedes echar un vistazo en este enlace shorturl.at/eszX9

Comment: En principio solo son 10